# LuaGnome compile error:Version 2.24.23-linux-amd64 not supported; can't download

Tags: linux, lua, gtk, gnome

i use ubuntu 14.04 64bit,i got a error message when try to compile LuaGnome when i  type the make command,the whole error message is as below:

```
Your Gtk Version is 2.24.23  
Version 2.24.23-linux-amd64 not supported; can't download.  
script/make-xml.lua failed.  The C file content is:  
#undef __OPTIMIZE__  
#define G_STDIO_NO_WRAP_ON_UNIX  
#include <glib-object.h>  
#include <glib.h>  
#include <gmodule.h>  
#include <glib/gstdio.h>  

make[1]: *** [build/linux-amd64/gnome/types.xml] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

does anybody know how to fix it?